# MUI DataGridPro, Adding functionality of Adding new row, editing a row, deleting a row to the DataGridPro Toolbar, with checkbox selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, toolbar, mui-datatable

I want to add the CRUD functionality to the Toolbar icons in the MUI DataGridPro.

The row editing should be enabled once the row checkbox is selected. On checkbox selection only, the particular row should be edited/deleted.

[The row manipulation should be possible once the row checkbox is selected, then clicking the toolbar options and performing the required task.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5dqs.png)

I am trying to build upon the MUI DataGridPro Editing example given on MUI website.
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/

I am attaching the demo.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bec9us?file=Demo.tsx

I tried using MUI DataGridPro apiRef, to write custom handlers for the events, but my understanding of it is vague and it starts giving the error
`apiRef.current.subscribeEvent is not a function`

Comment: You made several statements but you didn't ask for anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.